# Slashy String Literal not working in println

Tags: string, groovy

When i try execute the following code, which should just print a [slashy string](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Strings+and+GString#StringsandGString-SlashyStringliterals) in groovy console version 1.7.4 i get a compilation error:

`println /slashy string/`

if i change this to:

`def s = /slashy string/;
println s`

everything is fine and the expected string is printed.

Any ideas what i am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The final gotcha (on the linked doc) says, a slashy string cannot be used with `assert`, because of a grammar limitation. Since println is also a part of the grammar (afaik, since its not a classical java function), I would guess this applies here, too.

It says to use braces around it:

```
println (/slashy string/)
```

This worked fine in my groovy shell.

Comment: Yeah, this is working in my groovy shell too ;-) Thanks for your answer. I read the hint about the grammar limitation but i thought that only applies for assert statements (maybe the doc is not exact at this part).

from the groovy doc:
currently a slashy string can't be the left hand side (LHS) expression of an assert statement